# How can I understand javascript or jquery code inside in edittext?

Tags: java, c#, javascript, android, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a edittext wihch users can write something and post my server. I want to know how can I control the text include **javascript** , **jquery** or something else which has bad behavior ?

should I solve this android side or webservice side ? I use mvc 4.5 (I mean should I solve this c# side?)

thanks in advance

Comment: You should always do this on the server side, never trust the client! Take a look at [request validation in ASP.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The easiest way is HTML Encoding. BTW, there is no MVC 4.5

Comment: so how can I do this on dot net side? thanks for your advice

Comment: [Here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/security/preventing-javascript-injection-attacks-cs) is a small article about that. You need to look at the **Approach #2: HTML Encode in the Controller** part.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should move it to the server side.

Why ? Because if someone want to do bad things with your backend, he can easily do it directly with his computer thus bypassing your android side content purification.

He just have to launch Wireshark on his PC (or use a proxy to do MITM if you use HTTPS or SSL), listen the conversation your Android app and your server are having and then use that information to build an attack with his computer.

A lot of APIs are not securised enough because people are still thinking that people can't access it outside the apps, it's wrong, they can.